The constuction of the continuously deforming character on $A^\times/F^\times$
This question is came from bump, Automorphic forms and representations, p.349.

Let $k$ be a global field, $A$ its adele ring. $k_v$ the completion of $k$ at the place $v$ of $k$.
If $v$ is non-Archimedean, the valuation on $k_v$ we denoted by $\rm{ord}_v$. We set $O_v:=\{a\in k_v| \rm{ord}_v(a)\geq 0\}$, $\mathfrak{p_v}:=\{a\in O_v| \rm{ord}_v(a)>0\}$, and $q_v:=\# O_v/\mathfrak{p}_v.$,
The normalized absolute value on $k_v$:
$|\cdot |_v$ is the usual absolute value, if $k_v\cong\mathbf{R}$;
$|\cdot |_v$ is the square of usual absolute value, if  $k_v\cong\mathbf{C}$;
$|\cdot |_v=q_v^{-ord_v(a)}$, if $v$ is non-Archimedean.
Then $|a|_A:=\prod_v|a_v|,$ for all $a=(a_v)\in A^\times$. Now, let $\xi$  be the unitary character on $A^\times/F^\times$, i.e. the continuous group homomorphism from $A^\times/F^\times$ to $\mathbf{C}^1$. I want to show $\chi(y):=\xi(y)|y|_A^s$ change continuously as $s$ (a complex number) varied.
That is, for $s\in\mathbf{C}$, Given $\epsilon>0$, we need to find $\delta>0$ such if $|s-s'|<\delta$, such that $|\xi(y)|y|_A^s-\xi(y)|y|_A^{s'}|<\epsilon$.
$|\xi(y)|y|_A^s-\xi(y)|y|_A^{s'}|=|\xi(y)|||y|_A^s-|y|_A^{s'}|=||y|_A^s-|y|_A^{s'}|$, where the second equality came from $\xi$ is unitary. But now I have no idea on approximating $||y|_A^s-|y|_A^{s'}|$.

It seems to me you are trying to show that $s \mapsto |.|_A^s$ is continuous for the uniform topology on $\operatorname{Hom}(A^{\times},\Bbb C)$ (correct me if this is not the case). But this is not true: pick any $s \in \Bbb C$ and any $\delta >0$, you will find $y \in A^{\times}$ which makes the difference $||y|_A^s-|y|_A^{s+\delta}|$ arbitrarily large. Simply pick all coordinates to be 1, except for one place where the absolute value is massive.

However, if I remember correctly, this map is continuous IF we consider the compact open topology on $\operatorname{Hom}(A^{\times},\Bbb C)$.

I add the statement in the book. I'm not sure if I have misunderstood somethings or not.

Perhaps there is a mention of the topology on $\operatorname{Hom}(A^{\times},\Bbb C)$ earlier in the book, otherwise there are multiple options. For instance, they vary continuously with respect to the product topology (i.e. the pointwise convergence topology). You could maybe look at which arguments use this continuity, and try to infer from this the implied topology.
